# How do you print an associative array in DTrace?

Tags: arrays, printing, associative, dtrace

The question pretty much sums it up.  "dtrace 'print an associative array'" has exactly one google hit and the similar searches are equally useless.

**EDIT:**

If I were to use an aggregation, I'm not aware that I'd still be able to remove entries.  My application requires that I be able to do things like:

```
file_descriptors[0] = "stdin"
file_descriptors[3] = "service.log"

...
...


file_descriptors[3] = 0

...
...

# should print only those entries that have not been cleared.
print_array(file_descriptors)
```

I know that you can clear an entire aggregation, but what about a single entry?

**UPDATE:**

Since I'm doing this in OS X and my application is to track all of the file descriptors that have been opened by a particular process, I was able to have an array of 256 pathnames, thusly:

```
syscall::open*:entry
/execname == $1/
{
    self->path = copyinstr(arg0);
}

syscall::open*:return
/execname == $1/
{    
    opened[arg0] = self->path;
}

syscall::close*:entry
/execname == $1/
{
    opened[arg0] = 0;
}

tick-10sec
{
    printf("  0:  %s\n", opened[0]);
}

The above probe repeated 255 more times...
```

It sucks.  I'd really like to have something better.

Answer (score 1):

Is [this](http://markmail.org/message/2t7ygochpyl25mro) the link Google found?  Because the advice seems pretty sound:

> I think the effect you're looking for should be achieved by using an
>   aggregation rather than an array. So you'd actually do something like:

```
@requests[remote_ip,request] = count();
```

> ... and then:

```
profile:::tick-10sec
{
    /* print all of the requests */
    printa(@requests);

    /* Nuke the requests aggregation */
    trunc(@requests);
}
```

Comment: Oh - I see now what you are doing.  Aggregations aren't what you want unless you are collecting a bunch of data over the run for that key.  Sorry; I misunderstood.

Comment: No problem.  The issue is a bit of a tough nut to crack and I could have been clearer in my post...

Answer (score 1):

Use an associative array and `sum(1)` and `sum(-1)` instead of `count()`.

Answer (score 0):

print(array) seems to be defined to do what you want:

> The print action formats output based on the type information that DTrace knows about. The output data is formatted based on the type. The following rules cover the output format:

> Every entry in an array is printed.

https://illumos.org/books/dtrace/chp-fmt.html